# Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade from 21.10 error

Tags: upgrade, 21.10, 22.04

I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu from 21.10 to 22.04 with:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -c
do-release-upgrade
```

but I always get an error:

```
Hit http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                        
Hit http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x hirsute InRelease                     
Hit http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                 
Ign https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu impish InRelease        
Err https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu impish Release          
  404  Not Found [IP: 50.18.207.89 443]                                        
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
Hit http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                        
Hit http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                
Hit http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease              
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x hirsute InRelease                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                 
Ign https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu impish InRelease        
Err https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu impish Release          
  404  Not Found [IP: 184.72.30.82 443]                                        
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
Hit http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                        
Hit http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                
Hit http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease              
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x hirsute InRelease                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                 
Ign https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu impish InRelease        
Err https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu impish Release          
  404  Not Found [IP: 50.18.207.89 443]                                        
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      

Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is 
therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for 
repository creation and user configuration details., E:The repository 
'https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu impish Release' 
does not have a Release file.
```

I tried to remove `speedtest-cli`, remove snap of speedtest, but nothing helped. Any idea what could I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should comment out the unofficial repositories before upgrading. This can normally be done in 2 ways:

1. Commenting out the relevant line from `/etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Renaming the relevant files inside the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

When you have performed the upgrade, check your old repos/files, and update them accordingly to the latest version. After that you can uncomment and/or rename the files back to activate the repositories.

###### For solution 1:

Find the lines containing `https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x hirsute` and `https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu impish` and put a `#` in front of the line.

###### For solution 2:

Find the files inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` that contains the above repositories. Rename those files, so they don't end with a `.list` extension (for instance, rename them to `filename.list.old`).

Answer (score 2):

First we'll find the file that's causing your errors...

`cd /etc/apt`

`grep -i packagecloud.io sources.list`

You may get no "hits" with the `grep` command if sources.list doesn't contain it. That's ok.

---

Then we look elsewhere...

`cd sources.list.d`

`grep -i packagecloud.io *.list`

This should provide you with the filename(s) that we're looking for.

---

Now we edit the found file(s) with...

`sudo -H gedit found_filename.list`

It should only contain one or two lines. Place a "#" (no quotes) at the front of each line, save the file.

---

Optional extra points:

`grep -i deb.nodesource.com *.list`

`sudo -H gedit found_filename.list`

Change **hirsute** to **impish**, save the file.

---

`sudo apt update`

Should run cleanly without the errors that you previously had.

If you wish to keep speedtest-cli, use this command, taken from [here](https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/install)...

`curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/ookla/speedtest-cli/script.deb.sh | sudo bash`

Then install/reinstall speedtest-cli or speedtest if you wish.

Then you can do your upgrade.