# Upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 LTS errors

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, 21.10

Attempting to  upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 LTS gives me errors:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade

Ign:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Ign:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease           
Ign:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease            
Err:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release               
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Err:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                     
Err:10 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release  
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Get:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu hirsute InRelease [48.9 kB]
Hit:12 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com impish InRelease 
Reading package lists... Done                              
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This did not help: [Ubuntu 22.04 Upgrade from 21.10 error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405209/ubuntu-22-04-upgrade-from-21-10-error)

Any suggestions?

Comment: The link you provided won't work as Ubuntu 21.10 was still a *supported* product when the link you provided was done, you're dealing with an EOL product now thus have extra step(s). https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades